# Jtree navigator

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, listener, jtree

I would like to know how can I implement a navigator tree for my application in swing. I got a long sequence of panel, and I would like to have on left side of the screen a kind of "navigator". It seems easy as concept, but I really do not know where to start.
To get you a picture is something like this:

[image]

I would like to realize the "red zone" :)

Actually I'm able to construct the tree iterating through the arraylist provided by the controller, in this way:

```
Iterator<SectionPanel> sectionIterator = sectionPanelList.iterator();
    while (sectionIterator.hasNext()) {
         root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(sectionIterator.next()));
    }
```

The question is:  if I want to remove a particular object, how can I find it within the tree? Moreover, how can I connect an action with the relative JPanel ? I mean "when I click on Panelx, I would like the scroll to move and let me see that particular panel ".

Thanks for your attention.
Simone

Comment: Start with [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)

Comment: Or you could look at [SwingLabs](http://swingx.java.net/) [TaskPane](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=240)

Comment: I got a question. Actually I have an arraylist of object and I was able to construct the tree in this way:

Answer (score 2):

for showing one single `JPanel`, you can

- use [JTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) and to returns `String value` from [TreeSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#select)
- put [JPanels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) to the [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
- selection acme from `JTree` returns `String value` as paramanter for [CardLayout#show(Container parent, String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#show%28java.awt.Container,%20java.lang.String%29)
- for multiply the logics could be the same, but there will be x_times number of combinations